# Is it technically possible to mine specific transactions? Like ones made inside a club

Tags: solidity, transactions, gas, mining, nodes

playing with this thought experiment.

Would it be possible that miners get to choose the specific  transactions they would want to mine before another miner?

Scenario:
You create an NFT marketplace and want only the miners of the marketplace to mine the all the transactions from the dapp (minting, transferring, selling,etc). Is there a technical way to make this possible. If transactions are prices as low as possible, can a specific miner have enough time to mine it before others?. It doesn't matter if this doesn't make economic sense to the miner in question. Is it possible?

As i have been researching transactions dont really get assigned to any specific miner and the miners rather compete between each other to mine first the one with the biggest reward.Could a specific miner mine trx from x smart contracts exclusively. How would this work.

Could a custom RPC do anything?, change the nonce?

Thanks again for thinking ideas with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't arbitrarily mine a specific transaction since you'd have to propose a block yourself but if you have a node you can parametrize which transactions you can mine, just as some portion of the network who chose not to mine blocks that had transactions that interacted with Tornado Cash smart contracts

Answer (score 0):

Have the gasPrice as low as possible, so less likely other miners would pick the transaction. The dapp should collect the hash of initiated transaction  and tell your miner's etherium client, which will pick specific transactions from the mempool.